# can I reuse a filterchain in an ant script?

Tags: ant

I have a couple of filterchains I use for many different file concatenations.  Is there a way to reuse the filterchain in an ant script?

For example:

```
    <concat destfile="${client-pub-js}/site.js" fixlastline="no">
        <filterchain>
            <replacetokens>
                <token key="PRELOAD_FADE_IN_TIME" value="${PRELOAD_FADE_IN_TIME}"/>
                <token key="PRELOAD_HANG_TIME" value="${PRELOAD_HANG_TIME}"/>
                <token key="PRELOAD_FADE_OUT_TIME" value="${PRELOAD_FADE_OUT_TIME}"/>

                <token key="APP_FADE_IN_TIME" value="${APP_FADE_IN_TIME}"/>
                <token key="FONTKIT_ID" value="${fontkit.id}"/>
            </replacetokens>
        </filterchain>

        <filelist dir="${client-build-js}/lib">
            <file name="jquery.imagesloaded.js"/>
            <file name="LoadFade.js"/>
        </filelist>
    </concat>

    <concat destfile="${client-pub-css}/site.css" fixlastline="no">
        <filterchain>
            <replacetokens>
                <token key="PRELOAD_FADE_IN_TIME" value="${PRELOAD_FADE_IN_TIME}"/>
                <token key="PRELOAD_HANG_TIME" value="${PRELOAD_HANG_TIME}"/>
                <token key="PRELOAD_FADE_OUT_TIME" value="${PRELOAD_FADE_OUT_TIME}"/>

                <token key="APP_FADE_IN_TIME" value="${APP_FADE_IN_TIME}"/>
                <token key="FONTKIT_ID" value="${fontkit.id}"/>
            </replacetokens>
        </filterchain>

        <filelist dir="${client-build-css}/site">
            <file name="home.css"/>
        </filelist>
        <filelist dir="${client-build-css}/core">
            <file name="site.css"/>
            <file name="logo.css"/>
        </filelist>
    </concat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, described in the [ANT manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html)

Define a FilterSet and reference it later.

```
<filterset id="myFilterSet" begintoken="%" endtoken="*">
  <filter token="DATE" value="${TODAY}"/>
</filterset>

<copy file="${build.dir}/version.txt" toFile="${dist.dir}/version.txt">
  <filterset refid="myFilterSet"/>
</copy>
```

Comment: How is this _the_ answer? I know this will work for the example above, but it does not answer the question... AFAIK, a `filterset` is not the same as a `filterchain`. This doesn't seem like it will work generically (e.g. for the `loadFile` task)